# Dynamic Tab names in Tabholder in Django-crispy-forms

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I wondering is there any chance to use "dynamic" names for Tabs.

Like in next example Tab names are hardcoded 'First Tab' and 'Second Tab' in ModelForm. I have dynamic titles (head1, 2 etc.) for every tabs and I am using values from database for titles. I like to use same text dynamically in tab names.

```
    Tab('First Tab',
        HTML("""<h4>{{ head1.0 }}</h4>"""),
        'field_name_1',
        Div('field_name_2')
    ),
    Tab('Second Tab',
        HTML("""<h4>{{ head2.0 }}</h4>"""),
        Field('field_name_3', css_class="extra")
    )
```

I would like to add same dynamic title texts to tab names also like in next example, but I have not found solutions.

```
    Tab({{ head1.0 }},
        HTML("""<h4>{{ head1.0 }}</h4>"""),
        'field_name_1',
        Div('field_name_2')
    ),
    Tab({{ head2.0 }},
        HTML("""<h4>{{ head2.0 }}</h4>"""),
        Field('field_name_3', css_class="extra")
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you assign the value from the database to a variable and pass it in to the form?

```
title = value_from_database
    Tab(title,
        HTML("""<h4>{{ head1.0 }}</h4>"""),
        'field_name_1',
        Div('field_name_2')
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks David, solution you provided works fine. Now I can type titles only to one place.